# не срабатывает событие change при unchecked radio button

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events

Вопрос. В данном коде:

```
for(const tab of tabs) {
      tab.addEventListener(`change`, () => {
        if (tab.checked) {
          user.classList.add(`main-navigation__list-item--active`);
        } else if(!tab.checked) {
          user.classList.remove(`main-navigation__list-item--active`);
        }
      })
    }
```

почему при клике добавляется класс, а с предыдущего при этом не снимается? Это radio-buttons, событие `change`. По идее при клике на один, на предыдущем тоже должно срабатывать событие, но оно не срабатывает. Только на том, который кликнули. Else if не выполняется и класс остается на предыдущем табе

Comment: а html разметку нельзя добавить в вопрос ?

Answer (score 0):

Событие на radio-button вызывается только когда выбранный элемент меняется. При чем только 1 раз для того элемента который стал выбранным.

```js
let numOfChanges = 0;
const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('radio');

for(let radio of radioButtons) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    for(let radio of radioButtons) {
      if(radio.checked) {
        radio.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        radio.classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
    
    numOfChanges++;
    console.log(numOfChanges);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
```